# Importing two similar packages into eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I have two imports that I need to use:

```
import net.robotmedia.billing.model.Transaction;
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.Transaction;
```

and I receive the following error:

```
The import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.Transaction collides with another import statement
```

But I need to use both of these items.  How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the classes must be used by typing its fully qualified name. For example:

```
net.robotmedia.billing.model.Transaction tx = new net.robotmedia.billing.model.Transaction();
```

Remember that imports are just used to let you use a class by its simple name rather than using it with its fully qualified name. If you wanted, you could code all your classes without any import, and always use the fully qualified class names. It would just be much less readable and more cumbersome to write. But if two classes with the same simple name are used inside the same class, then you can only import one of them.